# Can I make the post type value dynamic in ajax.php in wordpress

Tags: wp-query, ajax

```
    <?php
    /*

    @package subhasishlive theme

        ========================
            AJAX FUNCTIONS
        ========================
    */

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_sunset_load_more', 'sunset_load_more' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_sunset_load_more', 'sunset_load_more' );
    function sunset_load_more() {

    $paged = $_POST["page"]+1;

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'Allkitchenposts',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => '10'
    ) );

    if( $query->have_posts() ):

        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();

            // get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
        ?>

              <div class="col-sm-6 single-post-news">
                <div class="single-post-content">
                  <div class="post-box reveal-block text-left">
                    <div class="post-box-img-wrap">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php 
                        if (has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() ) ){
                            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
                            ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
                        <?php
                        }else{
                        ?>

                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/news-thumb-01.jpg" class="img-responsive" />

                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>  

                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-box-caption">
                      <div class="post-box-title text-ubold"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="text-gray-base"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                      <ul class="list-inline post-box-meta list-inline-dashed list-inline-dashed-xs text-extra-small-10 offset-top-12 text-silver-chalice">
                        <li class="text-uppercase"><?php echo meks_time_ago(); ?></li>
                        <li class="p text-uppercase"><span>by <a href="testimonials.html"><?php the_author(); ?></a></span></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


        <?php
        endwhile;

    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    die();

}

?>
```

> Instead of 'post_type' => 'Allkitchenposts' I want to make this value dynamic based on my post type so that I can load content with ajax in different archive page just like I did bellow in archive-Allkitchenposts.php

```
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default sunset-load-more" data-page="1" data-url="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>">Load More...</a>
      </div>
```

> following is my ajax-load.js file

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){


$(document).on('click','.sunset-load-more', function(){

// this refers to the button itself
var that = $(this);
// reference to the data-page attribute value of the button
var page = $(this).data('page');
// next page reference
var newPage = page+1;
// reference to the data-url attribute value of the button
var ajaxurl = that.data('url');


$.ajax({

url : ajaxurl,
type : 'post', // post method of retriving data
data : {

    page : page,
    action: 'sunset_load_more'

},
error : function( response ){
    console.log(response);
},
success : function( response ){

    that.data('page', newPage);
    $('.sunset-posts-container').append( response );

}

});
});
});
```

> I want to know how to load more posts by ajax for differet custom post type archive pages ???? Currently I'm only able to do it for one post type only.
>   Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this on single-{post-type} .

```
$t_slug = get_query_var('post_type');

 <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default sunset-load-more" data-page="1" post_type =<?php echo $t_slug ;?> data-url="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>">Load More...</a>
  </div>

jQuery(document).ready( function($){


$(document).on('click','.sunset-load-more', function(){
var post_type = $(this).attr('post_type');
// this refers to the button itself
var that = $(this);
// reference to the data-page attribute value of the button
var page = $(this).data('page');
// next page reference
var newPage = page+1;
// reference to the data-url attribute value of the button
var ajaxurl = that.data('url');


$.ajax({

url : ajaxurl,
type : 'post', // post method of retriving data
data : {

    post_type : post_type ,
    page : page,
    action: 'sunset_load_more'

},
error : function( response ){
    console.log(response);
},
success : function( response ){

    that.data('page', newPage);
    $('.sunset-posts-container').append( response );

}

});
});
});


function sunset_load_more() {
$post_type = $_POST['post_type'];
    $paged = $_POST["page"]+1;

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => ' $post_type',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => '10'
    ) );
}
```

Comment: Yes your code is right, except for one thing.Instead of 'post_type' => 'Allkitchenposts', we have to write 'post_type' => $post_type :) But thanks.

Comment: Cheers! edited . :)